# how to display date in crystal reports?

Tags: vb.net, date, crystal-reports

How to display date coming from database in crystal reports from vb.net? im struggling on how to fix this problem. i cant trace what is the reason why my database field (date) is not showing in the crystal reports? if anyone know on how to fix this please help me. thanks a lot guys!

```
    Here is my code:

    Call conserver()
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE status='finished' AND sys_name='" & frmhome.cbosyshis.Text & "' AND mod_name LIKE'%" & frmhome.txtmodhis.Text & "%' AND dte BETWEEN '" & frmhome.dtdte1.Text & "' AND '" & frmhome.dtdte2.Text & "'"
    Dim dscmd As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, connectionsrvr)
    dscmd.Fill(ds, "complaint")

    connectionsrvr.Close()

    Dim objret As New CrystalReport2
    objret.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objret
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

This the output when i run the program:
[image: Date column]

Comment: what are you getting instead?  Are you getting any data at all?

Comment: So when you put the field in the report, it doesn't show any data?

Comment: Without showing us your code, it's complete guesswork.

Comment: This is a Q&A forum not a twitter, show us exactly where is the problem. Code preferably.

Comment: sir I updated my question pls check my code sir if theres wrong only column date is not showing value from database.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I wonder if you are passing the date parameters correctly. Remove the `dte Between` portion of the code and have the report look at all dates available. If that works, take a look at your date parameters. If not, check your database values.

EDIT:

Create a formula and put the following code in it:

```
toText({dte}, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Now put that in your report and see what happens. `{dte}` is your date field.

Comment: i tried all what you've said but still, it didn't work. :( i also check the database values

Comment: Is there any suppression in the report or on the date field that may prevent it from being displayed? Looking at your data in the screenshot, is the data in the date field an actual date or just made-up data like the rest? Make sure the data in the date field is in a proper date format (dd/MM/yyyy).

Comment: sir how to put this on vb.net? sorry sir. this is my first time to use crystal reports. please help me. :( i saw a formula tab beside on my report is this what you mean sir?

Comment: Yes, that formula goes in your Crystal report, not in your vb code.

Comment: okay sir. i already copy the code sir , and when i run the program it has an error. the machine says that error in formula :(

Comment: Change the formula to toText({dte}, "yyyy/MM/dd") or try simply toText({dte})

Comment: it says that this field is not known. how is it?

Comment: I don't know what the name of the field is. In your code you call it "dte". You need to use whatever the name of the field is in place of {dte}. It should be something like {tablename.fieldname}.

Comment: i put the code in formula tab like this: totext({DataTable.dte}), and when i run the program i get that kind of error.. the column name of my date in the database is dte

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I really believe that something is wrong with that field in your database.

Comment: maybe sir. ill try to check the odbc driver or the database itself.

Comment: the error still occurring, eventhough i set all the database field